# Put edittext values to database and display in another activity using listview

Tags: android, database, listview

I'm making an app where you send the email w/o using intents and I want to save a message as draft using database if the user feels like saving the message as draft.
The code to send the mail works but I get multiple errors for the database insertion part.
I want to display only some fields on edittext in the listview
 DBHelper.classs

```
public class DBHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;// Table name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
//public static final String COLUMN_FROM = "From";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "drafts";
public static final String _TO = "To";
public static final String _ID = "id";
public static final String _SUBJ = "Subject";
public static final String _CC = "CC";
public static final String _BODY = "Body";

private DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Context context;

public DBHelper(Context aContext) {
    this.context=aContext;
    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(aContext);
}
public void open() {
db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
}
public long insertdraft(String Id, String To, String CC, String Subject, String Body) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("ID", Id);
    contentValues.put("To", To);
    contentValues.put("CC", CC);
    contentValues.put("Subject", Subject);
    contentValues.put("Body", Body);
    return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public void insert(ContentValues cv){
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
}
public Cursor getAllDrafts() {
    String buildsql = "select * from drafts";
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{_ID, _TO, _CC, _SUBJ, _BODY}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static final String TAG = "TAG";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context aContext) {
        super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Create your tables here

        String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE drafts(id text, To text, CC text, Subject text, Body text)";
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

        database.execSQL(buildSQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Database schema upgrade code goes here

        String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
        Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);// drop previous table
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
    }

    public void close() {
        dbhelper.close();
    }
}
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText e,e0,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5;
int id=1;
private ListView lstNames;
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DBHelper db;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Read and show the contacts
    showContacts();
    final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Button save= (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("SendMailActivity", "Send Button Clicked.");

            String fromEmail = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.textfrom)).getText().toString();
            String fromPassword = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.textpass)).getText().toString();
            AutoCompleteTextView act= (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textto);
            String toEmails=act.getText().toString();
            String ccEmails = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.textcc)).getText().toString();
            Log.i("SendMailActivity", "To List: " + toEmails);
            String emailSubject = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textsub)).getText().toString();
            String emailBody = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textmsg)).getText().toString();
            if (!ccEmails.contains("@"))
                ccEmails = "";
            new SendMailTask(MainActivity.this).execute(fromEmail, fromPassword, toEmails, ccEmails, emailSubject, emailBody);
        }
    });
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textpass);
            EditText e0 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textfrom);
            EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textto);
            EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textcc);
            EditText e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textsub);
            EditText e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textmsg);
            //Log.i("SaveDraftActivity", "Save Button Clicked.");
            id++;
            String Id = Integer.toString(id);
            String toEmail = e1.getText().toString();
            String ccEmail = e2.getText().toString();
            String emailSubj = e3.getText().toString();
            String emailBod = e4.getText().toString();
            if (toEmail.length() != 0 && emailSubj.length() != 0) {
                //db.insertdraft(Id,toEmail,ccEmail,emailSubj,emailBod);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DraftActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("Id",Id);
                intent.putExtra("ETo", toEmail);
                intent.putExtra("CC", ccEmail);
                intent.putExtra("Subject", emailSubj);
                intent.putExtra("Body", emailBod);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
               /* e.setText("");
                e0.setText("");
                e1.setText("");
                e2.setText("");
                e3.setText("");
                e4.setText("");*/
        }
    });
}
```

CustomAdapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context,Cursor c){
    super(context,c);
}
    public View newView(Context context,Cursor cursor,ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_data, parent, false);
    return retView;
    }
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // here we are setting our data
    // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views
    TextView textViewto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dbto);
    textViewto.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

    TextView textViewsub = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dbsub);
    textViewsub.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(4))));

    TextView textViewbody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dbbody);
    textViewbody.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(5))));
}
}
```

Draft Activity

```
public class DraftActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
public static ArrayList<String> ArrayDraft = new ArrayList<String>();
private DBHelper db;
private ListView listView;
String s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_draft);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    db=new DBHelper(this);
    listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list);

    Intent in=getIntent();
    //s1=in.getExtras().getString("Id");
    //Integer i=Integer.parseInt(s1);
    s2=in.getExtras().getString("ETo");
    s3=in.getExtras().getString("CC");
    s4=in.getExtras().getString("Subject");
    s5=in.getExtras().getString("Body");


    /*final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayDraft);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String namez = adapter.getItem(i);
            Toast.makeText(DraftActivity.this, namez, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Intent intent = new Intent(DraftActivity.this,MainActivity.class);//.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, namez);
        }
    });*/
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(DraftActivity.this, db.getAllDrafts());
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });
    db.insertdraft(s2,s3,s4,s5);
    customAdapter.changeCursor(db.getAllDrafts());
}
```

}

THANKS :)

Comment: "but I get multiple errors" - What are the errors ?

Comment: thanks but it got solved. It was relating changecursor showing nullpointer exception maybe I didnt initialize the obj